# .htaccess 301 redirect problem

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, http-status-code-301

i try to redirect url's like:

> example.com/video/1640/video-name

to

> example.com/video/1640/video-name/

i've tried with:

```
RewriteRule ^video/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/$ video.php?id=$1&title=$2 [L]
RewriteRule ^video/([^/]*)/([^/]*)$ /video/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/ [R=301,L]
```

but it is not working

my currently htaccess file has only the first line:

```
RewriteRule ^video/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/$ video.php?id=$1&title=$2 [L]
```

and videos only loads at

> example.com/video/1640/video-name/

url type

i want to redirect the non-backslash url type

> example.com/video/1640/video-name

to the correct one (the one with the backslash)

How can i do this?

Comment: if the ID is only ever going to be a number, use `\d+` rather than `[^/]*`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your second rule should be `RewriteRule ^video/([^/]*)/([^/]*)$ /video/$1/$2/ [R=301,L]`

Or you could forgo the redirect totally, and just say `RewriteRule ^video/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/?$ video.php?id=$1&title=$2 [L]` which  will allow both to view your video.

Answer (score 0):

**Update** FallingBullets is right (see the comments on this answer), his answer better suites the OP's problem, so please ignore this answer (I am leaving it for reference, though).

---

Maybe you simply have to prefix your pattern with a `/?`? E. g.

```
RewriteRule ^/?video/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/$ video.php?id=$1&title=$2 [L]
RewriteRule ^/?video/([^/]*)/([^/]*)$ /video/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/ [R=301,L]
#            ^ these ones
```

instead of

```
RewriteRule ^video/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/$ video.php?id=$1&title=$2 [L]
RewriteRule ^video/([^/]*)/([^/]*)$ /video/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/ [R=301,L]
```

since you are anchoring the pattern at the beginning of the path (using `^`).

Comment: this has nothing to do with the question.

Comment: Why not? If this fixes his existing rewrite rule so that his redirection works it should be a solution to his problem. Or did I misunderstand the OP's question?

Comment: You misunderstand the question: his rewrite rules work, but he cant figure out how to redirect, Your solution would lead to it not working at all (possibly) since the leading `/` is unnecessary (make it `/?` to stop it breaking stuff that currently works :) )

Comment: You're right, thanks for pointing this out. Updated my entry accordingly.

Comment: you should also fix the second rewrite rule (for reference purposes)